# Insert white noise at function

Tags: python, numpy

Here's a sample of function that I would like to insert white noise.
I've taken it from [this link](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization/blob/master/examples/visualization.ipynb).

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def target(x):
    return np.exp(-(x - 2)**2) + np.exp(-(x - 6)**2/10) + 1/ (x**2 + 1)
x = np.linspace(-2, 10, 50000)
y = target(x)

plt.plot(x, y);
```

[image]

I want to insert white noise to this graph like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create one of a variety of [random distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions) and add it to your data. For example here's a normal distributed noise with a standard deviation of 0.05 added to all your observations (which I've reduced in number to display better):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 200 

def target(x):
    return np.exp(-(x - 2)**2) + np.exp(-(x - 6)**2/10) + 1/ (x**2 + 1)

x = np.linspace(-2, 10, n)

standardDev = 0.05
noise = np.random.normal(0, standardDev, n)

y = target(x) + noise

plt.plot(x, y);
```

[image]